# Copy of empty parquet to a stage

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-schema

I have a below copy command, where i generate a parquet out of the rows returned by a query. I also partition by some column. I am have requirement to copy an empty parquet(a parquet with column header but no data) on stage in case the query returns 0 rows.

I am doing this from inside a procedure and the query is passed as a parameter to it. Means the query is not fixed, thus using a union(as I have read on some post) is not an option.

```
copy into @<stageName>/baseFolder/  from (
    <a query that returns 0 rows>) 
    partition by (col1 || '/' || CAST(col2 as INT)) 
        FILE_FORMAT = <fileformat> HEADER=true  DETAILED_OUTPUT=true
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Within your SP just check the value returned from running the COPY INTO statement and if it says zero records were copied then run another COPY INTO statement that passes in the data necessary to create your dummy file.

Comment: There is no data t be copied. It has to eb an empty parquet with column headers and no rows.